# apexrest: controlling HTTP error codes on exceptions

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, http

Is it possible to control what HTTP error code apexrest returns when an exception occurs in the code?  By default it returns a 500 error and a developer who's working on the system that's consuming the API is complaining that this is misleading (and I tend to agree).  SF defines 500 in this context as an Apex error, but [generally 500 is "Internal Server Error"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) which would suggest more than failed validation.

It seems to throws the 500 on all unhandled exceptions, whether native or custom exceptions.  (We're doing a bunch of validation on the input params to the webservices, and throwing custom exceptions when validation fails.)

According to [this documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_methods.htm) SF determines the error code automatically.

Is there a better way to handle this?  Can I control the error code returned?  If so, what's the best pattern  here?

Do I try to handle all exceptions and construct a response to return instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below is a pattern I use to vary the status code returned. It only maps two categories of exceptions but if you need to you can add more. Note that only [status codes from this list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm) can be returned - you can't return [other status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

By catching `Exception` it handles most unplanned errors (but can't catch governor limit exceptions), and the purpose of the custom `EndUserMessageException` is to return a simple message - such as a validation error - along with the 400 status code. The client can then handle the 400 and 500 status codes differently.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/mypath/*')
global without sharing class MyRest {
  
    @HttpGet 
    global static void get() {
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        if (res == null) {
            res = new RestResponse();
            RestContext.response = res;
        }
        try {
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(doGet()));
            res.statusCode = 200;
        } catch (EndUserMessageException e) {
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage());
            res.statusCode = 400;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(
                    String.valueOf(e) + '\n\n' + e.getStackTraceString()
                    );
            res.statusCode = 500;
        }
    }

    private static Object doGet() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**PS**

If the request is doing DML, remember to do an explicit rollback as handling the exception stops the automatic rollback:

```
@HttpPost  
global static void post() {

    // Explicit rollback needed as exceptions are handled here
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();        
    try {
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(doPost());
        res.statusCode = 200;
    } catch (EndUserMessageException e) {
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage());
        res.statusCode = 400;
        Database.rollback(sp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(Strings.sanitizedMessage(e));
        res.statusCode = 500;
        Database.rollback(sp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you check for null `if (res == null)`? Isn't it guaranteed to always be initialized?

Comment: @Eduard It is not initialized when the code is called from Apex unit tests. But on reflection, perhaps better to do the initialization in the test code.